Unresponsive Alt+Shift+R key combination
Description:
I'm encountering a strange issue where the R key does not work when pressing Alt+Shift together. Other keys work fine with Alt+Shift, but R simply doesn't respond in this combination.
Environment:

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNOME)
Single keyboard layout (no layout switching issues)

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Checked for any conflicting keyboard shortcuts in Settings.
Verified gsettings for hidden keybindings using Alt+Shift+R.
Confirmed layout switching isn't using Alt+Shift.
Tried in a fresh user session, but the problem persists.

Has anyone else encountered this issue in Ubuntu 24.04, or do you have any other ideas for debugging the problem? Any help would be appreciated!
